# Update complexo Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

Bom dia,
Já fiz uma pergunta parecida, estou tentando complementar dessa ver com mais informações e partindo do mais básico.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class Artista
    {

        public Artista()
        {
        }

        public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Site { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }

    }

public class Endereco
    {

        public Endereco()
        {
            Municipio = new Municipio();
        }
        public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public int MunicipioId { get; set; }
        public virtual Municipio Municipio { get; set; }

    }

public class Municipio
    {
        public Municipio()
        {
        }

        public int MunicipioId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public string Cep { get; set; }

    }
```

A entidade endereço deve ser opcional, durante o cadastro posso informar o endereço ou não.

Configuração Fluent API

```
public class ArtistaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Artista>
    {
        public ArtistaConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.ArtistaId);

            Property(a => a.Nome)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(a => a.Email)
                .HasMaxLength(150);

        }


public class EnderecoConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
    {
        public EnderecoConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.EnderecoId);
            HasRequired(m => m.Municipio)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MunicipioId);

            Property(m => m.Cep)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasMaxLength(9)
                .HasColumnType("char");

        }
    }
```

O cadastro do artista é feito da seguinte forma:

```
public void Add(Artista obj)
        {

            ValidaEndereco(obj);

            Db.Set<Artista>().Add(obj);
            Db.SaveChanges();

        }

private void ValidaEndereco(Artista artista)
        {
            var endereco = artista.Endereco;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Logradouro)
                    & string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Numero)
                    & string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Bairro))
            {
                artista.Endereco = null;
            }
            else
            {
                artista.Endereco.Municipio = null;
            }



        }
```

O update:

```
public void Update(Artista obj)
        {
            AtualizaEndereco(obj);
            Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Db.SaveChanges();

        }

private void AtualizaEndereco(Artista artista)
        {

            var endereco = artista.Endereco;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Logradouro)
                    & string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Numero)
                    & string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Bairro))
            {
                artista.Endereco = null;
            }
            else
            {
                artista.Endereco.Municipio = null;
                endereco.Municipio = null;
                Db.Entry(endereco).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }



        }
```

Neste caso, quando cadastro um artista e não cadastro o endereço, funciona corretamente e não gera erro algum, porém quando vou editar este cadastro para adicionando um endereço o seguinte erro é mostrado:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been
>   modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Como já hávia dito em outro post, sempre programei com ADO e Stored Procedures, e sempre ouvi que estava perdendo tempo, que Entity Framework tem um ganho de produtividade muito grande, mas sinto que perdi totalmente o controle da aplicação. Sou totalmente leigo com EF, estou apanhando muito para fazer coisas "idiotas" as vezes coisas que estavam funcionando param de funcionar sem muita explicação, esta é uma aplicação que estou fazendo para estudar e não consigo sair do cadastro, quando uma parte funciona outra para de funcionar...

Se alguém precisar do fonte para verificar posso fornecer também...

Comment: Entendo o que você está passando. Normalmente a transição não é muito simples, mas é importante não chutar como fazer as coisas. Vou responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a modelagem é 0 ou 1 endereços para um artista, então sua modelagem está incorreta. Faça da seguinte forma:

```
// Repare que retirei os construtores das propriedades de navegação.
// Isto porque eles não são necessários. Toda inicialização de propriedades
// de navegação fica a cargo do Entity Framework. 

public class Artista
{
    [Key]
    public int ArtistaId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    // Aqui está o segredo da cardinalidade:
    // A chave primária de endereço também é a chave estrangeira para artista.
    // É a única forma de garantir que um endereço pertence a um, e apenas
    // um artista.
    [Key, ForeignKey("Artista")]
    public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
    public int MunicipioId { get; set; }

    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    public virtual Municipio Municipio { get; set; }
    public virtual Artista Artista { get; set; }
}

public class Municipio
{
    [Key]
    public int MunicipioId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Cep { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
}
```

Não é preciso usar as Entity Type Configurations.

Não entendi o que isso faz:

```
    private void ValidaEndereco(Artista artista)
    {
        var endereco = artista.Endereco;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Logradouro)
                & string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Numero)
                & string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Bairro))
        {
            artista.Endereco = null;
        }
        else
        {
            artista.Endereco.Municipio = null;
        }
    }
```

Mas é importante dizer que essa abordagem não está boa.

Tanto que o código que é importante faz menos sentido ainda:

```
    private void AtualizaEndereco(Artista artista)
    {
        var endereco = artista.Endereco;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Logradouro)
                & string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Numero)
                & string.IsNullOrEmpty(endereco.Bairro))
        {
            artista.Endereco = null;
        }
        else
        {
            artista.Endereco.Municipio = null;
            endereco.Municipio = null;
            Db.Entry(endereco).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

Não sei se esse endereço está vindo corretamente preenchido, mas o que é certo é que este código não vai funcionar.

Experimente fazer um teste *hard coded* como o abaixo:

```
    private void InserirEnderecoHard(Artista artista)
    {
        var municipio = Db.Municipios.First();
        var endereco = new Endereco {
            Logradouro = "Rua de Teste",
            Numero = "123",
            Bairro = "Bairro Teste",
            Cep = "12345-678",
            Municipio = municipio,
            Artista = artista
        };

        Db.Enderecos.Add(endereco);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Não havia colocado o "ArtistaId" na entidade endereço, pois a ideia era usar o "Endereco" para várias outras entidades, ex. clientes, fornecedores, etc, todos eles teriam endereço e seriam representados por esta entidade...

Comment: Fiz o cadastro com o seguinte código: **var municipio = Db.Municipios.First();
            artista.Endereco = new Endereco
            {
                Logradouro = "Rua de Teste",
                Numero = "123",
                Bairro = "Bairro Teste",
                Cep = "12345-678",
                Municipio = municipio,
                MunicipioId = municipio.MunicipioId
            };
            Db.Set<Artista>().Add(artista);
            Db.SaveChanges();** mas ao editar o cadastro o endereço não é alterado. **Db.Entry(artista).State = EntityState.Modified;**

Comment: Me indica um curso?

Comment: Estou escrevendo um curso. Se tiver interesse, me chame no chat para conversarmos. Sobre o código colocado em comentário, se a entidade já existe, você não usa `Add`. Usa a modificação do `State`, conforme minha resposta.

Comment: Sim, a entidade já existe, neste caso usei Db.Entry(artista).State = EntityState.Modified; os dados do artista foram alterados, mas o endereço não...

Comment: Ah, sim. Acho que vai precisar fazer o `Add` do endereço, então. O raciocínio é o mesmo. Vou alterar a resposta.

Comment: Sobre o curso tenho interesse sim, estou procurando o chat aqui.. :/

Comment: assim deu certo, porém neste caso eu não atualizo o Artista, apenas o endereço.. como faço para atualizar tudo, artista e endereço? tentei fazer Db.Entry(artista).State = EntityState.Modified; depois de atualizar o endereço, mas um erro é gerado..

Comment: Aí isto vale outra pergunta com o erro específico.

Comment: Ok, só mais uma dúvida, sobre DataAnnotations, você acha mais interessante usar DataAnnotations na classe de domínio? melhor que usar fluent api para configurar?

Comment: Muito melhor. A configuração fica descentralizada e mais simples de conferir.